# how return System.out.print(0) in a void method?

Tags: java, return

I am making a basic decimal-to-binary converter for a class and its set up for when the user enters a '0' for it to return a zero. I am not sure how to do that with a return statement.

```
public class binary1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        convert(input);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void convert( int input ) 
    {   
        if (input == 0) return System.out.print(0); //<-- here is my problem
        convert(input / 2);
        System.out.print(input % 2);
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't return any value from a void function. What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry for not being clear my code works but not for zero as you can see http://imgur.com/r0Cnxd2 i need to get it to work for zero as well.

Comment: You can't return `System.out.print(0)` from *any* method. Your question does not make sense. And don't expect people to chase links. They won't. The question you post here must be complete, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your return after the print line.  I am assuming you do not actually need to return a value but to exit the function.

```
    public static void convert( int input ) 
    {   
        if (input == 0) 
        {
           System.out.print(0);
           return;
        }
        convert(input / 2);
        System.out.print(input % 2);
    }
```

Comment: thank you exactly what i was looking for. i would upvote you but i don't have 15 reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

I am little confused what exactly you want but here is some modified code might help you.

```
public static int convert(int input) {
   if (input == 0){
     System.out.print(0);   
     return 0 ;     
   }
  convert(input / 2);
  System.out.print(input % 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you have posted fails to return anything.

If you intend to return the integer converted to binary, the simplest approach would be to return it as a `String`, like so:

```
public static String convert(int input) {
    if (input == 0)
        return "0";
    else
        return convert(input / 2) + (input % 2);
}
```

Note: You can simply use `Integer.toBinaryString(input)` to perform exactly this.